# Passing Data from View to Controller using multiple textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio

I'm currently making a user activity timesheet where users can log their hours in each activity. My problem is that users have different number of activities assigned, so I cannot make a generic model or us an existing one to accept the input parameters. My alternative is to have separate pages for each activity (so I can save the hours directly individual activity models) but that is clearly inefficient. So how do I do that?

EDIT:
To reiterate my problem (I'm new to MVC5). From tutorials I've watched, the way data was passed from View to controller using a button was through an HTTPPOST with the controller accepting a model. For example:

```
pubc class Model
{
  public int id {get; set;}
  public string name {get; set;}
}

public ActionResult Create()
{
   return View();
}
```

Create.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{             
@Html.TextboxFor(mode.Name)

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

By pressing the button the view passes the model to the create httppost

```
[HTTPPOST]
public ActionResult Create(Model model)
{
   /*code here*/
}
```

Now here's my problem, I have a list of activities of a user (each user having different number of activities) that get displayed in the view.

Foreach activity in Timesheet it puts the activity name and a textbox to logy View looks something like this

```
Activity         Hours Loggeed
<Activiti> 1       <textbox>
<Activiti> 2       <textbox>
<Activiti> 3       <textbox>
```

Now how do I create an action that can accept that model passed by the view and update the hours of all the activities listed in the timesheet.

Controller

```
public ActioResult Time()
{
  return View(Timesheet);
}

[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Time( /* What do I place here?*/)
{
}
```

Timesheet Model

```
public class TimeSheet
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public List<ActivityModel> Activities { get; set; }  
    public DateTime Day {get; set;}
}
```

Basically the Timesheet model has a user id and a list of activities assigned to that user for that specific day.

Activity Model

```
public class ActivityModel
{
   public int ID {get; set}
   public string Title {get; set;}
   public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Actually, you have a model(Timesheet Model) where quantity of activities is dynamic for particular user so this model fits to the case that you described("users have different number of activities assigned")... Please review your question and eventually add controller and view code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `Hours` property in `ActivityModel` class and use that property to pass the user input. Assuming it's an integer, here's what your model class would look like

```
public class TimesheetModel
{
    public TimesheetModel()
    {
        this.Activities = new List<ActivityModel>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public List<ActivityModel> Activities { get; set; }  
    public DateTime Day { get; set; }
}

public class ActivityModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Hours { get; set; }
}
```

I believe the controller get method would be something like this

```
public ActionResult Time()
{
    TimesheetModel model = new TimesheetModel();
    model.Activities = ... // get activities here

    return View(model);
}
```

The view code would be like this, which will generate textboxes based on how many `Activities` you pass in the controller get method above

```
@model TimesheetModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Activity
        </th>
        <th>
            Hours Logged
        </th>
    </tr>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Activities.Count; i++)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@Model.Activities[i].Title</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Activities[@i].Hours" value="@Model.Activities[i].Hours" /></td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

You can use `TimesheetModel` for the controller post method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Time(TimesheetModel model)
{
    foreach (var activity in model.Activities)
    {
        // pass activity.Hours to database here
    }
}
```

When you submit the form and execute the controller post method, all of the user input values will be in `model.Activities` property with the exact same order as the textboxes. For example if you enter `12` in the second row, then `model.Activities[1].Hours` will be `12`.

**UPDATE**

If you also want to pass the other properties of `ActivityModel`, I'd suggest using hidden fields. Below is an example of passing the `ID` property

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Activities.Count; i++)
{
<tr>
    <td>@Model.Activities[i].Title</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="Activities[@i].Hours" value="@Model.Activities[i].Hours" />
        <input type="hidden" name="Activities[@i].ID" value="@Model.Activities[i].ID" />
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

You can also save `Title` and `Description` using the same way if they won't be changed or displayed on the form. The key here is how you set the `name` and `value` attribute of each `<input>` tag based on the name of the property that you want to bind them to.

Comment: Does it have to be a for loop or would a foreach achieve the same thing?

Comment: If you're talking about the view code, then yes it has to be a for loop. The key here is the name attribute: `name="Activities[@i].Hours"`, you need the index there so the textbox value will be bound to the correct record in `model.Activities` when posting the form.

Comment: Thanks it worked. However only the hours attribute of the activities were saved. Everything else was null (Title, Description, etc.). Is there something missing?